# Read csv file in spark with comma in fields

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I have the following data, for which I need to prepare a schema file to read the data in spark.

```
id, date, producttype, description
1, 02/01/2020,Standard,["ABC, PQR"]
2, 03/02/2020,Standard,["ABC, PQR"]
3, 20/02/2020,Standard,["ABC, PQR"]
```

The schema file I prepared is:

```
COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH, NULLABLE, PRECISION, DATA_SCALE
1, id, NUMBER,,N,38,0
2, date,VARCHAR2,15,N,,
3, producttype, VARCHAR2,10,N,,
4, description, VARCHAR2,15,N,,
```

To verify this data in spark I'm using the below command:

```
val schema_a = StructType(List(StructField("id",IntegerType,true),
StructField("date",StringType,true),
StructField("producttype",StringType,true),
StructField("description",StringType,true)))
```

The data is placed in S3 bucket

```
a_read_schema = 
spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","π").schema(schema_a).load("s3://data/202003110000")
```

The output after reading this file is as below:

```
a_read_schema.show()

id, date, producttype, description
1, 02/01/2020,Standard,[ABCπ PQR]
2, 03/02/2020,Standard,[ABCπ PQR]
3, 20/02/2020,Standard,[ABCπ PQR]
```

How can I get the column description with comma in it?

Comment: How are you using your schema file?

Comment: @EdgarRamírezMondragón The Schema file is placed in EMR, and there is a wrapper script which gets the data using talend to S3 comparing the schema.

Comment: try StructField("description",ArrayType(StringType())

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi I tried this already. This doesn't for CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function available to do it I guess. ArrayType as mentioned in comments doesn't works with csv data type.

The other way around is to read in the comma separated file and then concat last two columns.

This can be achieved in the following way:

```
 val schema_a = StructType(List(StructField("id",StringType,true),
                                StructField("date",StringType,true),
                                StructField("producttype",StringType,true),
                                StructField("description1",StringType,true),
                                StructField("description2",StringType,true)))


spark.read.option("delimiter",",").schema(schema_a)
.csv(your-file-path)
.withColumn("description", concat_ws(",", col("description1"), col("description2")))
.drop("description1", "description2")
.show()
```